# find product and sum of two number given in base 14 and reply in base 14

Tags: java

I have written the following code to compute the sum and product of two numbers that will be be inputted in base 14. The answer should also be in base 14.

I don't have any compilation errors. but the answer is garbage. can anyone help me figure out where the issue is?

The program should prompt users for two 14-based numbers and then display the summation and the
product of those two entered 14-based numbers. The outputs should also be 14-based.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class H6_gedion {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] Answer;
        final int base = 14;
        Scanner get = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] input = new String[2];
        System.out.println("Welcome to earth!!\nPlease Enter two 14-based 
            numbers in the next line: ");
            input = get.nextLine().trim().split("\\s+"); String num1 = input[0]; String num2 = input[1]; ValidateNumInBase(num1, base); ValidateNumInBase(num2, base);
            //Answer = compute(toDecimal(num1, num2));
            //System.out.println(Answer[0] + " " + Answer[1]);
            toBase14(compute(toDecimal(num1, num2)));
        }


        public static void ValidateNumInBase(String num, int base) {
            char chDigit;
            for (int d = 0; d < num.length(); d++) {
                chDigit = num.toUpperCase().charAt(d);
                if (Character.isDigit(chDigit) && (chDigit - '0') >= base) {
                    System.out.println("cannot have digit " + chDigit + " in base " +
                        base);
                    System.exit(1);
                } else if (Character.isLetter(chDigit) && (chDigit - 'A') + 10 >=
                    base) {
                    System.out.println("cannot have digit " + chDigit + " in 
                        base " + 
                        base);
                    System.exit(1);
                } else if (!Character.isDigit(chDigit) &&
                    !Character.isLetter(chDigit)) {
                    System.out.println("Invalid digit character " + chDigit);
                    System.exit(1);
                }
            }
        }

        public static double[] toDecimal(String num1, String num2) {
            double val1 = 0;
            double val2 = 0;
            double decDigit = 0;
            char chDigit;
            int L = num1.length();
            for (int p = 0; p < L; p++) {
                chDigit = Character.toUpperCase(num1.charAt(L - 1 - p));
                if (Character.isLetter(chDigit)) {
                    decDigit = chDigit - 'A' + 10;
                } else if (Character.isDigit(chDigit)) {
                    decDigit = chDigit - '0';
                } else {
                    System.out.println("error: unrecognized digit");
                    System.exit(1);
                }
                val1 += decDigit * Math.pow(10, p);
            }
            L = num2.length();
            for (int p = 0; p < L; p++) {
                chDigit = Character.toUpperCase(num2.charAt(L - 1 - p));
                if (Character.isLetter(chDigit)) {
                    decDigit = chDigit - 'A' + 10;
                } else if (Character.isDigit(chDigit)) {
                    decDigit = chDigit - '0';
                } else {
                    System.out.println("error: unrecognized digit");
                    System.exit(1);
                }
                val2 += decDigit * Math.pow(10, p);

            }
            double[] decimalNum = {
                val1,
                val2
            };

            return decimalNum;

        }

        public static double[] compute(double[] decimalNum) {
            double sum = decimalNum[0] + decimalNum[1];
            double prod = decimalNum[0] * decimalNum[1];
            double[] Solution = {
                sum,
                prod
            };
            return Solution;
        }

        public static void toBase14(double[] Solution) {
            double val = Solution[0];
            //detrmine the number of digits in base 14
            int D = 1;
            for (; Math.pow(14, D) <= val; D++) {}

            //use char array to hold the new digits
            char[] newNum = new char[D];
            double pwr;
            for (int p = D - 1; p >= 0; p--) {
                pwr = Math.pow(14, p);
                double decDigit = Math.floor(val / pwr);
                val -= decDigit * pwr;

                if (decDigit <= 9) {
                    newNum[D - 1 - p] = (char)('0' + (int) decDigit);
                } else {
                    newNum[D - 1 - p] = (char)('A' + (int)(decDigit - 10));
                }
            }

            val = Solution[1];
            //detrmine the number of digits in base 14
            //int D =1;
            for (; Math.pow(14, D) <= val; D++) {}

            //use char array to hold the new digits
            char[] newNum2 = new char[D];
            //double pwr;
            for (int p = D - 1; p >= 0; p--) {
                pwr = Math.pow(14, p);
                double decDigit = Math.floor(val / pwr);
                val -= decDigit * pwr;

                if (decDigit <= 9) {
                    newNum2[D - 1 - p] = (char)('0' + (int) decDigit);
                } else {
                    newNum2[D - 1 - p] = (char)('A' + (int)(decDigit - 10));
                }
            }

            System.out.println("Sum: " + newNum.toString());
            System.out.println("Product: " + newNum2.toString());

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `"I don't have any errors. but the answer is garbage."` -- that sounds like a logic error to me, and so your first statement is not correct. Perhaps you meant to say that you don't have any "compilation" errors.

Comment: You've got too much code there. Divide and conquer -- split the code up into smaller testable units/methods and test them exhaustively. Read: [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for more debugging tips that you should be doing.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  We expect a few things from questions, and I suggest you read the sections on [how to ask questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922) and [providing mcves](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  As @HovercraftFullOfEels (great name) has pointed out, you are asking your code to do a lot of different things without clearly separating duties, which makes debugging logic errors needlessly difficult.  Break your code into steps (validation, casting as ints, change of base, math opps) and test each one individually.

Comment: If you are still having problems, post sample input and output that *clearly illustrates* what type of "garbage" is being produced.

Comment: Cleaned up formatting

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you may be trying to reimplement a feature that already exists; converting from a `String` to an `int` from a specified base.

The `Integer` class contains two methods that will be extremely helpful with this:

[`Integer.valueOf(String s, int radix)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf-java.lang.String-int-) will take a String as an input and attempt to convert it to the corresponding integer, where radix is the base of the number. `Integer.valueOf("D", 14)` would return 13. If, however, the String does not contain a parsable int the method will throw a `NumberFormatException`.

[`Integer.toString(int i, int raxis)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString-int-int-) will take an int as an input and return a string representation in the specified radix.

You can rely on the fact that `Integer.valueOf(...)` will throw an error if the input value is incorrect to re-prompt the user for an input. Further, arithmetic is defined for integers regardless of base.